# Create Array of Objects and count number of occurrence

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and want to create another array of objects based on.
I want to check if an object is repeated just want to show the count, otherwise show the object itself with count = 1.

```js
<!-- I have an array--> 
 var arr =[{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"kabab",price:250}];
 // I want to create another array based on "arr" like the one below
var test =[{name:"coke",price:20,count:3},{name:"kabab",price:20,count:1}];

//Any hint please
```

Comment: Nice problem. How are you coming with it?

Comment: The most important is the JavaScript code. So we need that code to help you. Otherwise, it seem that you are asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please check these links to learn [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What if there are two objects with the same name, but different prices?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

More or less...

```js
var arr = [{
  name: "coke",
  price: 20
}, {
  name: "coke",
  price: 20
}, {
  name: "coke",
  price: 20
}, {
  name: "kabab",
  price: 250
}];
// I want to create another array based on "arr" like the one below
// var test =[{name:"coke",price:20,count:3},{name:"kabab",price:20,count:1}];
var count = {};
var test = [];
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
  var id = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
  if (count.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    count[id].count++;
  } else {
    test.push(arr[i]); // Data contamination. Too lazy to copy object
    count[id] = test[test.length - 1]; // Could be better.
    count[id].count = 1;
  }
}
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. This answer considers `name` or some identifier will be unique for each object.

```js
counter = {}
var arr = [{
  name: "coke",
  price: 20
}, {
  name: "coke",
  price: 20
}, {
  name: "coke",
  price: 20
}, {
  name: "kabab",
  price: 250
}];

var obj = {};
var counter = {}

for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
  obj[arr[i]['name']] = arr[i];
  counter[arr[i]['name']] = (counter[arr[i]['name']] || 0) + 1
}
newArr = new Array();
for (var key in obj){
  newArr.push(extend( obj[key], {count:counter[key]}));
}

function extend(a, b){
    for(var key in b)
        if(b.hasOwnProperty(key))
            a[key] = b[key];
    return a;
}
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr =[{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"kabab",price:250}];
 var countNameMapping = {}, finalArr = [];

 var arrLength = arr.length;
 for(i=0; i<arrLength; i++){
    var tempObj = {name:arr[i], price:arr[i].price, occurance:1};
    var productName = arr[i].name;
    if(countNameMapping[productName] === undefined){
        countNameMapping[productName] = tempObj; 
    }else{
        countNameMapping[productName].occurance += 1;
    }
 }

 for(var k in countNameMapping){
    finalArr.push(countNameMapping[k])
 }
 console.log(finalArr );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
var arr =[{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"kabab",price:250}];

var result = [];

arr.map(function(arrObject) {
    if (result.length > 0) {
        result.map(function(resultObject) {
            if (resultObject.name != arrObject.name) {
                arrObject.count = 1;
                result.push(arrObject);
            } else {
                resultObject.count++;
            }
        })
    } else {
        arrObject.count = 1;
        result.push(arrObject);
    }
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will provide the result you are looking for:

```
var arr =[{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"kabab",price:250}];

var map = arr.reduce((accum, item) => {
  var obj = accum.get(item.name) || Object.assign({}, item, {count:0});
  obj.count++;
  return accum.set(item.name, obj);
}, new Map());
var res = [...map.values()];
```

Comment: This will probably not work if the array contains an object with the same name but a different price, which I assume the OP wants to retain as a separate item.

Comment: Indeed, but as OP didn't ask for that, I didn't do it. If that was the case though, the key of the map could be name and price.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably what are you looking for:

How does it work? 
First, your array `arr` will use a `forEach` loop to find each `object` and if if new you will add it to the `results` array. The method `isNew()` will return `true` if the object is new.

For each new object founded you will count the number of occurrences using `findOccurrences()` To reduce the number of "loops" you will slice the array according to the index. So you don't need to search again over the already processed data.

So now you can build an *new object*, using the name, price and count.

Finally, you can `push()` the *new object* to the `results` array.

```js
var arr =[{name:"coke",price:20},{price:20,name:"coke"},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"kabab",price:250}];
var results = [];
var index = 0;

var originalDiv = document.getElementById('original');
var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');

arr.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (isNew(obj)) {
    var counter = findOccurrences(obj, arr.slice(index, arr.length));
    var newObj = {
      name: obj.name,
      price: obj.price,
      count: counter
    }
    results.push(newObj);
  }
  index++;
});


printArray(arr, originalDiv);
printArray(results, resultsDiv);



function isNew(newObj) {
  var wasFound = true;
  if (typeof results != "undefined" && results != null && results.length > 0) {
    results.forEach(function(obj) {
      if (newObj.name === obj.name && newObj.price === obj.price) {
        return false;
      } else {
        wasFound = false;
      }
    });
    return !wasFound;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function findOccurrences(newObj, objects) {
  var count = 0;
  if (typeof objects != "undefined" && objects != null && objects.length > 0) {
    objects.forEach(function(obj) {
      if (newObj.name === obj.name && newObj.price === obj.price) {
        count++;
      }
    });
  }
  return count;
}

function printArray(objects, div) {
  var count = 0;
  if (typeof objects != "undefined" && objects != null && objects.length > 0) {
    objects.forEach(function(obj) {
      var newElement = document.createElement('p');
      newElement.innerHTML = 'item ' + count + ': ';
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        newElement.innerHTML += key + ': ' + obj[key] + ', ';
      });
      newElement.innerHTML = newElement.innerHTML.slice(0, -2);
      div.appendChild(newElement);
      count++;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="original"><p>Original Array</p></div>
<div id="results"><p>Results Array</p></div>
```

**Update**:
More optimization.

```js
var arr =[{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"kabab",price:250},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"coke",price:20},{name:"kabab",price:250}];
var accumulator = {};
var results = [];

var index = 0;

var originalDiv = document.getElementById('original');
var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');

String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
  var hash = 0;
  if (this.length == 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    var char = this.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + char;
    hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
  }
  
  var c = (hash & 0x0FFFFFFF)
    .toString(16)
    .toUpperCase();

  return '0000000'.substring(0, 7 - c.length) + c;
};

arr.forEach(function(obj) {
  var id = JSON.stringify(obj).hashCode();
  console.log(id);
  if (accumulator.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    accumulator[id].count++;
  } else {
    results.push(obj);
    accumulator[id] = results[results.length - 1];
    accumulator[id].count = 1;
  }
});

printArray(arr, originalDiv);
printArray(results, resultsDiv);

function printArray(objects, div) {
  var count = 0;
  if (typeof objects != "undefined" && objects != null && objects.length > 0) {
    objects.forEach(function(obj) {
      var newElement = document.createElement('p');
      newElement.innerHTML = 'item ' + count + ': ';
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        newElement.innerHTML += key + ': ' + obj[key] + ', ';
      });
      newElement.innerHTML = newElement.innerHTML.slice(0, -2);
      div.appendChild(newElement);
      count++;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="original">
  <p>Original Array</p>
</div>
<div id="results">
  <p>Results Array</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Using stringify is a horrible idea.

Comment: Stringification will incorrectly report that `{a: 1, b: 2}` and `{b: 2, a: 1}` are different. You can search for "deep equality" to find good ways to compare two objects for equivalence.